# Systemd timer every second Monday?

Tags: systemd-timer

It is possible to run a timer every 15 minutes like so:

```
OnCalendar=*:0/15
```

Is there a way to run that timer every second Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While as of the time of writing this is still [an outstanding issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6024), it is possible, as per [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/systemd/comments/jfayw1/calendar_expression_for_1st_and_3rd_wednesday_of/), run action every 1st and 3rd Monday of the month. This was good enough for my needs, although is likely to leave a 3 week gap at the end of the month.

```
Mon *-*-01..07,15..21 02:00:00
```

This matches every Monday between 1st and 7th as well as 15th and 21st of any month, at 2am.

Comment: Thank's for suggestion.